# What is the most complete binary quadratic form table?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

Is there a free, easily accessible quadratic form resource — maybe even just a big web-accessible table — which shows “all known results” [reasonably speaking] about numbers of the form $mx^2+ny^2$ for various $m,n$?

> Immediate motivation: Given integers $a$ and $x$ with $a^3 \mid (x^2+1)(3x^2+5)$, I’m trying to characterize $a$. I know that if [odd] prime $\phi \mid (x^2+1)$, then $\phi \equiv 1\!\pmod{4}$… but what about $\phi \mid (3x^2+5)$?

Ultimately, of course, this kind of question really comes down to characterizing the primes that can divide a given quadratic form. I know about scattered resources like [this Mathworld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticResidue.html) and [the (very short!) table on this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html) — I just can’t seem to find comprehensive information on that subject presented in a nice compact form.

Comment: I would consult David A. Cox's book *Primes of the Form* $x^2 + ny^2$ (especially for its references).

Comment: for odd primes that do not divide the discriminant $D,$ all you need is that Legendre $(D|p) = 1.$  Briefly, these are the primes that are represented by any form of that discriinant, for you $u^2 + 15 v^2$  or $3u^2 + 5 v^2.$ List of values $\pmod {60},$ then special treatment for $2,3,5$

Comment: Do you mean "Given integers $a$ and $x$"?

Answer (score 1):

Particular case where $(x, 3)=1$

For $3x^2+5$ we may write:

$x^2\equiv 1\bmod 3\Rightarrow 3x^2+5\equiv 8\equiv 2\bmod 3$

We may conclude that primes of the form $p=3m+2$ can divide $3x^2+5$ , for example:

$x=1\rightarrow 3x^2+5=8, k=0\rightarrow p=2; 2|8$,

$x=6\rightarrow 3x^2+5=113=3\times 37+2$

$x=4\rightarrow 3x^2+5=53=3\times 17+2$

$x=8\rightarrow 3\times 64+5=197=3\times 65+2$

$x=17\rightarrow 3x^2+5=872=2\times 436; 2=3\times 0+2$

$x=18\rightarrow 3x^2+5=977=3\times 325+2$

For $mx^2+ny^2$ we may use the same method, suppose $(m, n, 3)=1$ then:

$mx^2+ny^2\equiv (m+n)\bmod 3$